# matlab genetic algorithm solver complex input and output

Tags: matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm

My Matlab program has multiple inputs as a struct (`in.a`, `in.b`, etc.)
and multiple outputs (`out.a`, `out.b`, etc.)

I would like to use the genetic algorithm solver from teh optimization toolbox to find the best input `in.a`, while all the other inputs are constant. The fitness is one of the outputs, e.g. `out.b(2,3)`.

How do I "tell" the solver this?

Thanks
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not uncommon in programming to have a situation where what is most convenient for your function and what some library call expects of it don't agree. The normal resolution to such a problem is to write a small layer in between that allows the two to talk; an *interface*.

From `help ga`:

> X = GA(FITNESSFCN,NVARS) finds a local unconstrained minimum X to the
>       FITNESSFCN using GA. [...] FITNESSFCN accepts a vector X of size
>       1-by-NVARS, and returns a scalar evaluated at X.

So, `ga` expects vector input, scalar output, whereas you have a structure going in and out. You would have to write the following (sub)function:

```
function Y = wrapper_Objfun(X, in)
    in.a = X; %# variable being optimized
    out  = YOUR_REAL_FUNCTION(in); %# call to your actual function
    Y    = out.b(2,3); %# objective value
end
```

and then the call to `ga` will look like

```
X = ga(@(x) wrapper_Objfun(x,in), N);
```

where `N` is however large `in.a` should be.

Also have a read about it in [Matlab's own documentation on the subject](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/toolbox/optim/ug/brhkghv-7.html).

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, I was hoping for some magic trick :/

Comment: thanks for the awesome answer and the brilliant link!